# Are there any poker websites that accept bitcoins?

Tags: websites

I would think that bitcoins would be a great fit for websites that allow for gambling, and with Texas Hold 'em being such a big card game it seems that a Hold 'em site might allow players to use bitcoins to fund their accounts. Does anyone know of a reputable poker site that accepts bitcoins?

Comment: OK, I just found a new site called Bet with Bitcoin (http://betwithbtc.com) and there are poker forums there with some info as well (http://betwithbtc.com/simplemachinesforum/index.php?PHPSESSID=3ptrgpqp3d5t970tehokb48g97&board=30.0)

Comment: In case anyone cares, I've settle on sealswithclubs.org as a BTC hold'em site.  Very friendly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best resource to look for a poker site is [the gambling section on bitcointalk.org](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=56.0).  There are a lot of smaller sites advertised in that section of the forums trying to cater to the poker players who want to use their bitcoins.

I think I've also seen people will to trade bitcoins for money on bigger poker sites, but I do not believe any major sites accept bitcoins directly at this time.

Answer (score 8):

[SwitchPoker.com](https://www.switchpoker.com), [Sealswithclubs.org](http://Sealswithclubs.org), [btcontilt.com](http://btcontilt.com), and [betco.in](http://betco.in) have Bitcoin Poker.

Comment: The site that I like most right now out of those is Seals With Clubs.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [BTC On Tilt](http://btcontilt.com/) a few times and I like it. They have a nice interface and constant free rolls during the day.

Comment: I just went over and created an account at BTC On Tilt and I like it so far.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the GAMES section on http://stuffexists.com/

It shows:

[BtcOnTilt.com](https://secure.btcontilt.com/register.php?referred=osmosis) , 
BitJack21.com ,
StrikeSapphire.com ,
BitWorldPoker.com ,
Betco.in ,
SealsWithClubs.org

Answer (score 1):

as of this writing there is only one site to play bitcoin poker on, and that's sealswithclubs.eu - they have games running almost all the time / very fast cashouts / no contest

Answer (score 1):

Switch Poker is a real money poker site, and it accepts bitcoins:

[Switch Poker](https://www.switchpoker.com/?rid=2400)

Answer (score 0):

I'd second http://betwithbtc.com/ as a good resource for gambling related bitcoin sites.

Along with the bitcoin centric poker sites mentioned in other answers switchpoker.com takes bitcoin as a payment method along with other more traditional payment methods.